# How to retrieve process ID for IE browser instance using Ruby or WATIR?

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, watir, browser-automation, watir-classic

IE Browser instance is open.  How do I get the process id for the Browser instance or opened tab for the browser using WATIR or Ruby:

```
require "Watir"
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "www.google.com"
puts Watir::Browser::Process.process_id_from_hwnd browser.hwnd
```

Comment: try to write the code as it is written in VBS (http://knowledgeinbox.com/forums/uft-qtp-bpt-st/how-to-get-the-value-of-'process-id'/msg2711/?PHPSESSID=ic462ndn21q3b9thsjlj59tnd6#msg2711)..

Comment: take hints from http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.in/2007_02_01_archive.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didint help in my case.

Comment: I don't have Windows right now.. I had once

Comment: Are you using Watir-Classic or Watir-Webdriver?

Comment: I am using 'watir', '2.0.1'

Comment: i tried to execute following code in env.rb but getting error.

$process_id =   Watir::IE::Process.process_id
puts $process_id

Error:uninitialized constant Watir::IE::Process (NameError)

Comment: please show us the code you are using (edit your question and insert it)  especially your requires and how you create your browser object.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'watir-classic'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
Watir::Browser::Process.process_id_from_hwnd browser.hwnd
```

here is the above tested via IRB

```
C:\Users\Chuck>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'watir-classic'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x22f00454 url="about:blank" title="">
irb(main):003:0> Watir::Browser::Process.process_id_from_hwnd browser.hwnd
=> 3752
```

This is however newer version than you are using, so your mileage may vary

```
C:\Users\Chuck>gem list watir

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

commonwatir (4.0.0)
watir (5.0.0 x86-mingw32)
watir-classic (4.0.1)
watir-webdriver (0.6.11)
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs but am still getting the Error "uninitialized constant Watir::Browser::Process (NameError)" for the code u have suggested.I tried following in env.rb through netbeans which has Ruby plugins and also i have ruby1.8.7 

ENV.rb file contains following code:

require "Watir"

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "www.google.com"
puts Watir::Browser::Process.process_id_from_hwnd browser.hwnd

getting error after running above code:
uninitialized constant Watir::Browser::Process (NameError)

Comment: For Watir v2.0.1, it will need to be `Watir::IE::Process.process_id_from_hwnd browser.hwnd`. Note the need for `Watir::IE` instead of `Watir::Browser`.

Comment: Thanks Justin, its working for me with following code,

    browser = Watir::Browser.new
    puts Watir::IE::Process.process_id_from_hwnd browser.hwnd